# Session array storage in Zend Framework 2 throwing warning

Tags: php, session, zend-framework

I'm having a issue with `Zend\Session\Storage\SessionArrayStorage.php`. I'm not entirely sure what is going on, as the login/identity was working fine and quite literally just broke for some reason. The only thing I can think of what I did was adding a paginator route but I took that out in hopes of fixing the error(s) but it didn't do anything.

Here are the warnings:

```
Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, integer given in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Session\Storage\AbstractSessionArrayStorage.php on line 400
Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Session\Storage\AbstractSessionArrayStorage.php on line 374
```

It repeats this error a bunch of times (if it helps, here is a screenshot of the error - https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6Epy.jpg)

The way I have it setup is that the session service is set in Module.php, and uses the file LoginAuthStorage.php to handle the saving, and finally calling it via the service registered in global.php

Here is the entire code I think is relevant:

Global.php

```
    'service_manager' => array(
          'aliases' => array(
              'Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService' => 'pblah-auth',
           ),

           'invokables' => array(
               'pblah-auth' => 'Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService',
           ),


        'session' => array(
            'config' => array(
                'class' => 'Zend\Session\Config\SessionConfig',
                'options' => array(
                    'name' => 'p-blah',
            ),
        ),

        'storage' => 'Zend\Session\Storage\SessionArrayStorage',

        'validators' => array(
            'Zend\Session\Validator\RemoteAddr',
            'Zend\Session\Validator\HttpUserAgent',
        ),
     ),
  ),
```

Module.php

```
use Zend\Authentication\Storage;
use Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService;
use Zend\Authentication\Adapter\DbTable\CredentialTreatmentAdapter as DbTableAuthAdapter;

public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
             'Application\Model\Storage\LoginAuthStorage' => function($sm) {
                 return new LoginAuthStorage();
             },

             'MemberAuthService' => function($sm) {
                  $db_adapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                  $auth_adapter = new DbTableAuthAdapter($db_adapter, 'members', 'username', 'password');

                  $auth_service = new AuthenticationService();
                  $auth_service->setAdapter($auth_adapter);
                  $auth_service->setStorage($sm->get('Application\Model\Storage\LoginStorage'));

                  return $auth_service;
             }
        ),
    );
}
```

Controller:

```
namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

use Application\Form\LoginForm;
use Application\Model\Filters\Login;
use Application\Model\Storage\LoginAuthStorage;


class MemberLoginController extends AbstractActionController
{
    protected $storage;
    protected $auth_service;
    protected $login_service;
    protected $mem_service;


    public function indexAction()
    {
        if ($this->getAuthService()->hasIdentity()) {
            return $this->redirect()->toUrl('/members');
        }

        $form = new LoginForm();

        return new ViewModel(array(
            'form' => $form
        ));
    }


    public function authAction()
    {
        $form = new LoginForm();

        $request = $this->getRequest();

        if ($request->isPost()) {

            $login = new Login();

            $form->setInputFilter($login->getInputFilter());
            $form->setData($request->getPost());

            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $login->exchangeArray($form->getData());

                // first make a quick password_verify check
                if (!$this->getLoginService()->verifyPassword($login)) {
                    $this->flashMessenger()->addErrorMessage('Invalid username and/or password');

                    return $this->redirect()->toUrl('login-failure');
                }

                // check first if a session is already active
                if (!$this->getLoginService()->checkSession($login->username)) {
                    $this->flashMessenger()->addErrorMessage("A session is already active with that username.");
                    return $this->redirect()->toUrl('login-failure');
                }

                $this->getAuthService()->getAdapter()
                ->setIdentity($login->username)
                ->setCredential($this->getLoginService()->verifyPassword($login)['pass']);


                $result = $this->getAuthService()->authenticate();

                foreach ($result->getMessages() as $message) {
                    $this->flashMessenger()->addMessage($message);
                }

                if ($result->isValid()) {
                    if ($login->remember_me == 1) {
                        try {
                            $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Application\Model\Storage\LoginAuthStorage')->rememberUser(1);

                            $this->getAuthService()->setStorage($this->getServiceLocator()->get('Application\Model\Storage\LoginAuthStorage'));

                            $this->getLoginService()->insertSession($login->username,
                                $this->getLoginService()->verifyPassword($login)['pass'], session_id());
                        } catch (\Exception $e) {
                            echo $e->getMessage();
                        }
                    } else if ($login->remember_me == 0) {
                        try {
                            $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Application\Model\Storage\LoginAuthStorage')->rememberUser(0);

                            $this->getAuthService()->setStorage($this->getServiceLocator()->get('Application\Model\Storage\LoginAuthStorage'));

                            $this->getLoginService()->insertSession($login->username,
                                $this->getLoginService()->verifyPassword($login)['pass'], session_id());
                        } catch (\Exception $e) {
                            echo $e->getMessage();
                        }
                    }

                    $this->getAuthService()->getStorage()->write($login->username);

                    return $this->redirect()->toUrl('/members');
                } else {
                    $this->flashMessenger()->addErrorMessage('Invalid username and/or password');

                    return $this->redirect()->toUrl('login-failure');
                }
            } else {
                return new ViewModel(array('form_error' => 'Validation Error while logging in, please try again.'));
            }
        }
    }


    public function loginfailureAction()
    {
        return new ViewModel(array());
    }


    public function getAuthService()
    {
        if (!$this->auth_service) {
            $this->auth_service = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('MemberAuthService');
        }

        return $this->auth_service;
    }


    public function getLoginService()
    {
        if (!$this->login_service) {
            $this->storage = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Application\Model\LoginModel');
        }

        return $this->storage;
    }
}
```

LoginAuthStorage

```
   namespace Application\Model\Storage;

use Zend\Authentication\Storage\Session;


class LoginAuthStorage extends Session
{
    /**
     * Sets the time for the user to be remembered after login
     * @param number $default
     * @param number $time
     * @return void
     */
    public function rememberUser($default = 0, $time = 1209600)
    {
        if ($default == 1) {
            $this->session->getManager()->rememberMe($time);
        } else if ($default == 0) {
            $this->session->getManager()->rememberMe(0);
        }
    }


    /**
     * Destroys the session information
     * @return void
     */
    public function forgetUser()
    {
        $this->session->getManager()->forgetMe();
    }
}
```

index.phtml (where `$this->identity()` is being called)

```
<h4 class="w3-center"><?php echo "Welcome " . $this->identity(); ?></h4>
```

and MembersController -

```
 namespace Members\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;



class MembersController extends AbstractActionController
{
    protected $profile_service;
    protected $groups_service;


    public function indexAction()
    {
        $params = $this->identity();

        $dir = array_diff(scandir(getcwd() . '/public/images/profile/' . $params . '/', 1), array('.', '..', 'current', '.htaccess'));

        if (count($dir) > 0) {
            $images = array();

            foreach ($dir as $value) {
                $images[] = "<img src=\"/images/profile/$params/$value\" class=\"w3-margin-bottom w3-round w3-border\" style=\"width: 100%; height: 88px;\">";
            }

            $layout = $this->layout();

            natsort($images);

            $layout->setVariable('my_images', $images);
        }
    }


    public function getProfileService()
    {
        if (!$this->profile_service) {
            $this->profile_service = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Members\Model\ProfileModel');
        }

        return $this->profile_service;
    }


    public function getGroupsService()
    {
        if (!$this->groups_service) {
            $this->groups_service = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Members\Model\GroupsModel');
        }

        return $this->groups_service;
    }
}
```

If it also helps, here is the Members Module.php

```
namespace Members;

use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\AutoloaderProviderInterface;
use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;
use Zend\Http;
use Members\Model\ProfileModel;
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;
use Members\Model\Filters\EditProfile;
use Members\Model\EditProfileModel;
use Members\Model\GroupsModel;


class Module implements AutoloaderProviderInterface
{

    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
                __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
            ),
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . str_replace('\\', '/' , __NAMESPACE__),
                ),
            ),
        );
    }


    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }


    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
        $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);

        $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, array($this, 'checkCredentials'));
        $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, array($this, 'configureLayout'));
    }


    public function checkCredentials(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $matches = $e->getRouteMatch();

        if (!$matches) {
            return $e;
        }

        $route = $matches->getMatchedRouteName();

        if (0 !== strpos($route, 'members/') && $route !== 'members') {
            return $e;
        }

        $auth_service = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('pblah-auth');

        if (!$auth_service->hasIdentity()) {
            $response = $e->getResponse();
            $response->setStatusCode(302);
            $response->getHeaders()
            ->addHeaderLine('Location', $e->getRouter()->assemble([], array('name' => 'home/member-login')));
            $response->sendHeaders();
            return $response;
        }

        return $e;
    }


    public function configureLayout(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        if ($e->getError()) {
            return $e;
        }

        $request = $e->getRequest();

        if (!$request instanceof Http\Request || $request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            return $e;
        }

        $matches = $e->getRouteMatch();

        if (!$matches) {
            return $e;
        }

        $app = $e->getParam('application');
        $layout = $app->getMvcEvent()->getViewModel();

        $controller = $matches->getParam('controller');

        $module = strtolower(explode('\\', $controller)[0]);

        if ('members' === $module) {
            $layout->setTemplate('layout/members');
        }
    }


    public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'Members\Module\EditProfileModel' => function ($sm) {
                    $table_gateway = $sm->get('EditProfileService');
                    $profile = new EditProfileModel($table_gateway);
                    return $profile;
                },

                'EditProfileService' => function ($sm) {
                    $db_adapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                    $result_set_prototype = new ResultSet();
                    $result_set_prototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new EditProfile());
                    return new TableGateway('profiles', $db_adapter, null, $result_set_prototype);
                },

                'Members\Model\ProfileModel' => function ($sm) {
                    $table_gateway = $sm->get('ProfileService');
                    $profile = new ProfileModel($table_gateway, $sm->get('pblah-auth')->getIdentity());

                    return $profile;
                },

                'ProfileService' => function ($sm) {
                    $db_adapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                    return new TableGateway('profiles', $db_adapter);
                },

                'Members\Model\GroupsModel' => function ($sm) {
                    $table_gateway = $sm->get('GroupsService');
                    $group_model = new GroupsModel($table_gateway, $sm->get('pblah-auth')->getIdentity());

                    return $group_model;
                },

                'GroupsService' => function ($sm) {
                    $db_adapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                    return new TableGateway('groups', $db_adapter);
                }
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

I did do a check on `$this->identity()` to see if it was working and it was passing the username but again, the two warnings just keep showing up on the page a number of times.

If more information is needed, I can try and post more.

Comment: What happens when you replace `'pblah-auth' => 'Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService'` with `'pblah-auth' => 'Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory'`? (Assuming you are using the latest version of the framework)

Comment: @User210411 Did you ever find a solution for this one?

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if somehow that the session global variable contains an integer instead of an array in `$_SESSION['__ZF']`.

What you can try to do is dump the `$_SESSION` variable like this to see what is actually in it:

```
\Zend\Debug\Debug::dump($_SESSION);
```

Next, try clearing your session and then see again what happens after logging in.

Comment: it's saying it's null. I've logged out and back in but its still doing it.

Comment: Try dumping it before the application starts doing anything with a regular `var_dump` then. Also, have you tried clearing the session from the browser or unsetting it in PHP?

Comment: yes, I cleared the session in my browser and the logout calls forgetUser() and clearIdentity() which was working fine before, I'm not sure.

Comment: it lets me log in but whenever i called $this->identity() it shows the warnings (at least I think that is what the issue is linked to)

Comment: Can you edit your post to reflect where `$this->identity()` is called? It may be that it is called before it is available.

Comment: I added it, I hope that is enough?